# Overlay HTML on a Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to add HTML content over the top of a Google Map using Google Maps API? I want to add a `div` with other HTML content in it.

P.S. Not looking to manipulate the Google Info Window.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think it is possible, from the balloons or editing the html with javascript (something like `document.getElementByID(theGoogleMapsID).innerHTML+=<div>...</div>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this nice library.

http://blog.mridey.com/2011/05/label-overlay-example-for-google-maps.html

With some adjustments it can be used to add what ever content you want.

This is how you add it as an overlay not InfoWindow.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest and quickest way is to use the InfoBox library which is part of 
google-maps-utility-library-v3

You can find the docs under:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/

and examples under:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/

InfoBox extends the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 OverlayView class and allows you to adjust the layers to your needs without worrying about InfoWindows limitations.

Comment: That seems to do the same thing yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it´s possible with infowindows.

Example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=es#InfoWindows

Comment: I would love to give you a +1 but my reputation does not allow me.